# return value from other array angular 1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

**how can i return value from other array?**
i use ionic with angular 1

in angular 1, i have two arrays for example:

```
$scope.customers = [{id:1111, name:"Milan Shop", city:"Milan"},{id:2222, name:"roma Shop", city:"Roma"}]

$scope.SizeOfCustomers = [{id:1111, size:"big"},{ id:2222, size:"small"}]
```

i display with a list the customers with ng-repeat="x in customers"
and i like to display the value "size" from "SizeOfCustomers" array in this list.

the id is the key (it is a unique value for each customer), so i want to search the "id" of each customer in the "SizeOfCustomers" array and return the value of "size"

can somone help in here?

Comment: This is a pure JS issue. Just prepare the model so that you have an array of customers with an D, a name, and a size. The template is then tricial to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.customers.forEach(function(customer){
  $scope.SizeOfCustomers.some(function(sizeOfCust){
      if(sizeOfCust.id === customer.id){
        customer['size'] = sizeOfCust.size;
      }
      return (sizeOfCust.id === customer.id);
  })
})
```

and then do `ng-repeat` , you'll have access of size property.